# What does multiprocessing.pool actually do?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

**My question:** Is my code right now with multiprocessing.pool does what it is supposed to do?

```
def create_empty_file(file_name):
#for file in file_name:
#   print(file)
#create a file named based on "file_name" argument if it doesnt exist in library
    file = open(file_name, "x")
    #delay 30 seconds
    time.sleep(30)
    #close the program
    file.close()

#nodes should retrieve the next file to create as soon as one is done


#this will takes in argument as the file name
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #so takes in the argument (names of files) 
    files = sys.argv[1:-1]
    #number of processes
    n_process = int(sys.argv[-1])
    #create pool
    pool = Pool(processes=n_process)
    pool.map(create_empty_file, files)
```

My code does what it is supposed to do, but I'm not sure if my code actually works the way I am asked to.

Comment: Did you run it? What happened?

Comment: A complete aside; please make sure your comments share the same level of indentation. I'm finding this really hard to read.

Comment: It creates files based on the input (does what it is supposed to do), but I'm just not sure how it works.

Comment: Yes, that's how `pool.map` works, if by node you mean process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pool.map` is essentially feeding a shared multiprocessing queue that all of the worker processes draw from. Each worker runs an infinite (or fixed iteration if `maxtasksperchild` is set) loop that:

1. Tries to pull a task from the queue (blocking if none are available)
2. Processing the task
3. Sending the result back to the parent
4. goto 1

It doesn't try to pull a new task until the old one is done, so if one worker is getting cheap tasks, it will do more of them; no worker sits idle as long as tasks remain available. So yes, it's doing exactly what you want it to; it's not some round robin or other static work distribution scheme that could leave workers idle while others are overloaded with multiple tasks waiting. Setting a `chunksize` can create that effect, but in that case it's more about each "chunk" counting as a single task; the chunks then get distributed on demand, rather than the individual tasks.